# How to suppress updating of weight while allowing update of bias of a neural network layer (in pytorch, may need the same in tensor flow)

Tags: pytorch

During training I want to keep the weight of the input layer same, while allowing the bias to
be updated. I am using pytorch right now, but want the same for tensor flow too.

Currently as a work around I reset the weight every epoch. This is not efficient. Will like to get access to the internals to disable the update. I am assuming zero_grad_ will not work as it will disable both weight and bias. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `requires_grad` flag to `False`. For example

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

layer = nn.Linear(8, 8, bias=True)

layer.weight.requires_grad_(False) # set grad to False for weight but not bias

# grab old weights
old_weight = torch.clone(layer.weight.data)
old_bias = torch.clone(layer.bias.data)

opt = optim.SGD(layer.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
x = torch.randn(1, 8)
y = layer(x)
loss = y.sum()
loss.backward()
opt.step() # update step

new_weight = layer.weight.data
new_bias = layer.bias.data

(new_bias == old_bias).all()
>False

(new_weight == old_weight).all()
>True
```

You also seem confused about the `zero_grad` function. This is for removing old gradients before computing new gradients. It is unrelated to choosing which parameters are updated. You can read more [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/zeroing_out_gradients.html)

Comment: Thanks Karl that is very helpful. A related question, is there a way to set a limit (max  limit on the value of bias?)

Comment: You can do something like this

`layer.bias.data = layer.bias.clamp(min=-0.1, max=0.1)`